# Is it correct to call a static variable local?

Tags: c, variables, memory, static, keyword

It is known that the C language supports two kinds of memory allocation through the variables in C programs:

> 1) Static allocation is what happens when you declare a static
>   variable. Each static variable defines one block of space, of a fixed
>   size. The space is allocated once, when your program is started, and
>   is never freed.
>
> 2) Automatic allocation happens when you declare an automatic
>   variable, such as a function argument or a local variable. The space
>   for an automatic variable is allocated when the compound statement
>   containing the declaration is entered, and is freed when that compound
>   statement is exited.

(this is a full quote from http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_3.html)

The question is: is it correct to call a static variable in a function "local" in terms of memory allocation and why?
Thanks to everyone in advance.

P.S. any quotes from the C standard are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C standard doesn't define the term of *local variable*. *Automatic* and *static* refer to *storage duration*.

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects
>
> An object has a storage duration that determines its lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

You could call it a "function-local static variable" or something like that, but if you simply call it a "local variable" you may find that people are surprised when they find out it's actually static, and therefore has some of the properties of a global variable.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that as far as I understand it, such variable is local only in terms of scope.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of static variables in C.

1. The global static variables, where the `static` states that these variables can only be seen in this translation-unit.
2. Static variables with a local scop (i.e. in function). These are initialized once and keep their value event after going out of scope.

And to you question: no, a variable can't be `static` and `automatic` at the same time.
If you check their addresses, you will se that the `static` variable does not live on the current stack frame.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of variables, the term *local* most often denotes visibility and scope rather than the storage mechanism and lifetime.

Using the term *local variables* in C is in fact inaccurate as the standard never talks about that.

Informally, a static variable inside a function could be said to be *local* within the visible scope of the function, but not much more than that.

I would suggest against using the term *local variables* at all. Instead, one should talk about static variables within a function, automatic variables, static variables in the file scope and globals.

Comment: "Global scope" (the whole program), "file scope" (outside functions, but `static`) and "block scope" (defined inside `{ ... }`).

Answer (score 1):

> The question is: is it correct to call a static variable in a function "local" in terms of memory allocation and why?

Static variables are stored in the data section of the memory allocated to the program.
Even though if the scope of a static variable ends , it can still be accessed outside its
scope , this may indicate that , the contents of data segment , may be independent 
of scope.

Example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int increment(void);

int main()
{
printf("\ni = %d",increment());
printf("\ni = %d",increment());
printf("\ni = %d",increment());
}

int increment(void)
{
static int i = 1;
return i++ ;
}
```

In the above example , after each function call to increment() , the static variable i  inside the function goes out of scope every time the function returns but persistently
retains its value. This is only possible because the variable is not on the same same stack as the function , but it is present entirely in a different memory area , the data segment.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @HighPredator Do have a look at the above example

Comment: Just so that I understand this example. First, at the "return" statement function returns control to the caller. Secondly, a temporary variable is created to store the incremented value of "i". Am I right?

Comment: yes , you are in a sense right , understand it this way , returning a variable from a function , is similiar to passing a parameter to a function . There is an anonymous variable created and destroyed in between.Read more about it here http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/

Comment: @BarathBushan, that depends. When returning a `struct` (yes, it's legal), what probably happens is that the called function copies the result into space provided by the caller.